# Vue.js Creating Reusable Functions

Tags: vue.js

My code is horrible. I'm new on this Vue.js. As you can see I have two AJAX call that needs to become a function. How I'm going to do it.  I can't use for example

```
var app = this
this.allAdmissions('http://localhost/school/api/admissions', app.admission)
```

and then in my methods I will just

```
allAdmissions: _.debounce( function(url, value){

                axios.get(url)
                    .then( function(response ){
                        value = response.data.admissions

                    })
                    .catch( function(error){
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }),
```

It doesn't work. I need to create a function to combine this two.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        value: '',
        admissions: [],
        schoolyear: []
    },

    created: function(){
        this.allAdmissions('http://localhost/school/api/admissions')
        this.allSchoolYear('http://localhost/school/api/schoolyear')
    },
    methods: {

        allAdmissions: _.debounce( function(url){
                var app = this
                axios.get(url)
                    .then( function(response ){
                        app.admissions = response.data.admissions

                    })
                    .catch( function(error){
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }),
        allSchoolYear: _.debounce( function(url){
                var app = this
                axios.get(url)
                    .then( function(response ){
                        app.schoolyear = response.data.schoolYear

                    })
                    .catch( function(error){
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            })



    }
})
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I could see you have typo here `this.allAdmissions('http://localhost/school/api/admissions', app.admission)`, you are using singular `app.admission` but actual array name is addmissions, so It should be `app.admissions`

Comment: No it's still doesn't work. I used `app.admissions ` but still doesn't work.

Comment: are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: I will update with screenshot.

Comment: If I used console.log('value.admissions'). There is no observer but if I use the app.admissions it has an observer. I think that is the reason.

Comment: Observer is normal thing added by Vue to track changes on object.

Comment: But without observer it doesn't work. If i only pass  `var app=this this.allAdmissions('http://localhost/school/api/admissions', app )` then invoke `value.admissions` this work.

Comment: If you only pass the one parameter to your `allAdmissions` method (url), the `value` during function execution would be set to undefined

Comment: Yes it is undefined. So I pass two parameters.

Comment: Yes and then as I see from your image, value is filled with data from server ? So where is the actual problem, and what doesn't work as suposed ?

Comment: The problem is I need to combined the two methods by just passing the url and the data but it won't work. If you have idea how to make it only one method and just pass a parameter that's what I want. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't filled to my select if there is no observer. Although the data is there if no observer it won't filled up.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand what issue you have, and what you are trying to make...if you want we can continue discussion on chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139077/discussion-between-rbex-and-belmin-bedak).

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using promises for the ajax request which is a great step forward. I would suggest creating a separate js object with a single entrypoint (public) method to consolidate the logic of making both requests. this single object would return a composed promise that is resolved when both requests are fulfilled. take a look at Promise.All for this. then you would call your custom method from the ready hook inside the vue instance. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all.

what this will get you is code that is easier to reason about and debug for typos or any other flow mistake you may have made.

Also another suggestion is that you use arrow functions for your callbacks like so.

```
.then((response) => {
    this.admissions = response.data.admissions
 })
```

what this will allow you to do is skip the

```
var app = this
```

binding so that 'this' retains the reference to your current vue instance.